# Não sei se está certo meu pseudo código

Tags: pseudocódigo

1. Faça um pseudocódigo e fluxograma que entre com 3 valores e gere a equação de 2 grau, verifique as possíveis raízes.
   Delta= (b*b) -(4*a*c), verificar se o Delta for maior que 0, menor 0 ou igual a 0.

Fiz assim, não sei se está totalmente correto.

```
Inicio_algoritmo

      Declare: A, B, C e  D numéricos 
Escreva: “Digite três valores para verificar se o delta é maior que 0, menor que 0 ou igual a 0”
Leia: A, B, C 
D <- ((b*b) -(4*a*c))
Se (D > 0) 
Escreva “X1 = “ (-B + RaizQ(D)/ (2*A),  “X2 = “ (-B – RaizQ(D)/(2*A) 

Senão_se (D == 0)
Escreva “X1 = “ (-B + RaizQ(D)/ (2*A),  “X2 = “ (-B – RaizQ(D)(/2*A)

Senão
Escreva “ Não há raízes, delta menor que 0. ” 

Fim_algoritmo
```

Comment: A lógica está certa, quanto à sintaxe dos comandos tenho minhas dúvidas.

Comment: Um detalhe: se delta é zero, a raiz quadrada também é zero e as duas raízes são iguais a `-B / (2*A)` (não precisaria calcular a raiz quadrada, e poderia fazer a conta apenas uma vez antes de escrever)